# Angular Appending on element from directive make browser crash

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I trying to access a secured image url, I made this directive to get the secured image that returns the base64 of the current image. Everything is working fine. my problem is that when the request is done. I get this error in chrome "Aw, Snap!"

```
<my-image src="base_url" token="token"></my-image>



directive('myImage', ['$http' , function ($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        src: '=',
        token: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $http.get(scope.src, {
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + scope.token
            }
        }) .success(function (data) {
            scope.$watch('myImage', function () {
                element.append('<img src="'+data+ '" />');
            });
        }).error(function (data) {

        });
      }
    }
}]);


app.controller("myController", ["$scope", 
  function ($scope)
  {
      $scope.base_url = "api.securedsite.com/image/img.png";
   });
```

Comment: You do realize your src is "base_url" and token is "token" right? And you are trying to put a watch on your directive? Can't do that.

Comment: yup. but the base_url returns a base64 version of image. the base url is something like this api.site.com/img/this.jpg, but it returns a base64 code of the image.

Comment: what do you mean it returns a base url? base_url is just text. Are you meaning to use {{base_url}}?

Comment: Either way, you cant put a $watch on the directive itself.

Comment: why does the element.append make the browser crush? btw. I added some edits on my question about my controller.

Comment: See my answer for example of what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to clean this up a little, you dont need to assign the scope variables to attributes then pass them through an isolated scope to your directive. You will already have access to the same variables. The error however is from trying to put a watch on your directive itself. That is what is crashing chrome.

html:

```
<my-image></my-image>
```

js:

```
directive('myImage', ['$http' , function ($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       $http.get(scope.base_url, {
           headers: {
             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + scope.token
           }
        }).success(function (data) {
           element.append('<img src="'+data+ '" />');
        }).error(function (data) {
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: if i use something like this `<my-image src="{{base_url}}" token="{{token}}"></my-image>` the request is not working and the value of scope.src  is '{{base_url}}'

Comment: Do you have ng-controller="myController" on one of the outer html tags? If it works the other way then do that but I don't see how it could.

Comment: yup. I thought {{base_url}} is for output purpose only?

Comment: You might need to use ng-src instead then. using {{base_url}} is taking the value of $scope.base_url and putting it in place of {{base_url}}

Comment: Now that I look at this again you have all sorts of stuff confused.   the directive scope is trying to get variables that arent there as well.

Comment: Yes amongst many other things. Give me a minute and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. btw. What if I have an array of base_url. does this still work?

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean. Like multiple base urls in an array that it will randomly use one of them?

Comment: for example <div ng-repeat="base_url in base_urls"><my-image></my-image></div>